# Call a method async and then wait for it, are there benefits?

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous

I'm looking at some code doing the following:

```
Task<SomeType> t1 = 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Service.GetSomething(readQuery, contextId));
Task.WaitAll(t1);
```

Is there a benefit doing just one async task and then wait for it? Execution time will be the same (if not more due to some overhead that async will add), but maybe something at the processor level?

I'm just trying to figure out if this code is unnecessary (which I think it is) and if I can change it to a simple call, thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Seems a bit pointless - seems like you are doing more work since another thread may spin up to handle the task and essentially you've got the original just sitting there pulsing until it unblocks...(though I'm by no means an expert on multi-threading!)

Comment: This just adds unnecessary overhead. You aren't benefitting from asynchrony at all. Move the code after `WaitAll` to a callback method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a benefit doing just one async task and then wait for it? Execution time will be the same (if not more due to some overhead that async will add), but maybe something at the processor level?

Typically, there is no benefit (and extra overhead involved), *unless* you're performing other work between the time you start the task and when you block to wait for it.

In certain scenarios there *may* be a benefit, but this would only be true if you were scheduling the `Task` with a specific `TaskScheduler` which unloaded the work in a particular manner (ie: push the task onto a UI thread).

Also - typically, if waiting on a single task, instead of using `Task.WaitAll`, you can just call `Wait()` (or fetch the `Task<T>`'s `Result`):

```
// Just block until it's done
t1.Wait();

// OR:

// Block then get the result
SomeType result = t1.Result;
```

`Task.WaitAll()` is really only appropriate if you're waiting on more than one task.